# 1004 error: unable to get the StDev_S property of the WorksheetFunction Class

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the spreadsheet data that I'm working with.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aEgf29yigbwbemJdToJrlws9iJFMamUztM0PbdrsOQw/edit?usp=sharing

It highlights the line
    `.Cells(4, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)`
and I'm not sure why.  I printed the range and all the values are what I was looking for.  I've done similar worksheetfunctions with ranges in the past and haven't had a problem.

Here is the Code that I'm Using

```
Sub run_stats()

Dim i As Long
Dim nrows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range


For i = 3 To 50
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, i), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, i).End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In rng
        Debug.Print cell.Value
    Next cell
    With Worksheets("Statistics")
        .Cells(4, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
        .Cells(5, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) + (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng))
        .Cells(6, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) + Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
        .Cells(7, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
        .Cells(8, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) - Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
        .Cells(9, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) - (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng))
        .Cells(10, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
        .Cells(11, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Corrected code

```
Sub run_stats()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim i As Long
Dim nrows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Worksheet("Statistics").Range("C4:AX35").ClearContents

For i = 3 To 50
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, i), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, i).End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In rng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(cell) Then
            cell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cell
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) >= 2 Then
        With Worksheets("Statistics")
            .Cells(4, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
            .Cells(5, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) + (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng))
            .Cells(6, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) + Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
            .Cells(7, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
            .Cells(8, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) - Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
            .Cells(9, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) - (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng))
            .Cells(10, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
            .Cells(11, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
        End With
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your data in Sheet1 for error values such us #N/A. You can try this workaround that changes error values to empty string:

```
Option Explicit

Sub run_stats()

Dim i As Long
Dim nrows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range


For i = 3 To 50
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, i), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(11, i).End(xlDown))
    For Each cell In rng
        Debug.Print cell.Value
        'check if value is error -> change to empty cell if it is
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(cell) Then
            cell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cell
    With Worksheets("Statistics")
        .Cells(4, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
        .Cells(5, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) + (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng))
        .Cells(6, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) + Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
        .Cells(7, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
        .Cells(8, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) - Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng)
        .Cells(9, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng) - (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(rng))
        .Cells(10, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
        .Cells(11, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: works great.  I had to add in an if statement along with your answer to make sure that there were at least two non error items in each rng. will edit with fixed code